# SQLite and multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, locking

I am using SQLite and .Net 4.5, Winforms

I have a single table with only one column and several threads running at the same time. I want the first thread to read the value from the first row, then delete it, then the next thread should again read the first value that is now different and delete it, and so on... How do I achieve this?

Let me try and describe what happens now. Lets say I have one single column "Names" in the table with these values:

John

Bob

Albert

When I run my application with three threads, the first one reads "John," the second one reads "John," and the third one reads "John." After that, the "John" row is deleted.

I want the first thread to read "John" and delete the row, the second thread to read "Bob" and delete the row, the third thread to read "Albert" and delete it.

More info:

Each thread opens its own connection to the database.

Each thread uses the same method to read the value and then delete the row using the same connection, pseudo code of the method is:

open connection

read the value

delete the row

close connection

I can post the actual code, but I don't think the problem is in my code. I am looking for a way to "lock" the table when a thread is reading and deleting the thread, but can't seem to find a way of doing it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [transactions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html):

```
BEGIN;
SELECT Name FROM MyTable LIMIT 1;
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE Name = :WhatIveJustRead;
COMMIT;
```